# Pandas Rename Columns based on Lookup Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to rename columns in a dataframe using another dataframe as a lookup table based on matching AccountId and MappedField. The Lookup Table contains the AccountId, MappedField and FieldName.

Desired Logic:

1. Join Lookup Table and Raw Data on Lookup Data AccountId = Raw Data Account Id and LookupTable MappedField = Raw Data column name.
2. Rename the Raw Data column name using the Lookup Table FieldName value.

I have not been able to figure out how this can be done. I would greatly appreciate some help and guidance on this topic. Thank you in advance!

```
lookup_table = pd.read_excel(r'./../Reporting/Templates/ReportingData.xlsx')
account_list = [1001030,1001025]

for x in account_list:
    query = "select * from table where AccountId = ?;"
    
    df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn, params=[x])
```

**Lookup Table**
[image: Lookup Table]

**Raw Data**
[image]

**Desired Results**
[image: Expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dict from the lookup table, then pass the dict to rename the columns.

```
lookup_table = pd.read_excel(r'./../Reporting/Templates/ReportingData.xlsx')
account_list = [1001030,1001025]

for x in account_list:
    query = "select * from table where AccountId = ?;"
    new_col_names = lookup_table[lookup_table['Accountld']==x].set_index('MappedField')['FieldName'].to_dict()    
    df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn, params=[x]).rename(columns=new_col_names)
```